# How can I add additional storage space to a KVM virtual machine?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, linux-kvm

I have a centos host machine running a windows 10 guest machine. I am trying to add additional storage space to it. The method I tried so far was to create a new qcow2 image and then create a new ide disk in virt-manager and link it to the qcow2 image. However, that method doesn't seem to work as I don't see the new disk when I start the VM.

Comment: Yoyr methodology is broadly correct. Maybe your Windows system is missing appropriate drivers. Try using a SCSI rather then IDE definition in the KaVM setup.

Comment: I think I figured this out. I used IDE rather than SCSI, but in the VM I pressed win+x and went to disk management, the drive should be there but unallocated. right click on it and press new volume and it should be added